# WebRTC: Safari does not detect any output devices

Tags: javascript, safari, webrtc

I call this method to get available devices.

```
const availableDevices = async () => {
  await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true});
  return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {
    console.log(devices)
  })
}
```

It detects only input devices, but no output. Works in chrome perfectly but not in safari.
Current version of Safari - 14.0.3

Comment: Yes, only Chrome exposes these, what would ypu do with it anyway? IIRC only Chrome exposes the setSinkId method, which is still the only one where output devices are used.

Comment: Correct, i would not do anything with that because of missing setSinkId method.